# Performance of Linq Contains

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to filter a linq query using a list of filters and I plan on using the contains method to do so. So it will look something like this.

```
List<string> filter = new List<string>();
filter.Add("foo");
filter.Add("bar");
//Additional filters go here, max of about 10 filters
var test = dbcontext.books.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.name)).ToList();
```

The table behind this query has a lot of records (500,000), a PK identity field and an index on the field I'll be querying.

My questions is before going down this route would you expect the performance of this query to be acceptable or should I use a different approach on such a large dataset?

Comment: Define "acceptable performance".

Comment: Linq2Objects or Linq2SQL? If the latter, SQL server should optimize it away. The former, it depends, but generally a magnitude slower.

Comment: @leppie it always amazes me what EF can do to even the simplest of queries. I swear it has a Rube Goldberg layer in the SQL generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine; that will just translate to

```
select x.* from [books] x where x.name in (@p0,@p1)
```

with `@p0 = 'foo'` and `@p1 = 'bar'`; as long as `name` is indexed it should do fine. It gets more interesting, though, if `filter` gets very large. 10 items sounds fine. I'm also implicitly assuming it won't **return** all 500,000 - but will restrict to a sane number; if not, consider adding some `.Take(number)` limits.

If concerned, just measure it. It is pretty easy to run a SQL trace, or use a profiling tool.

Comment: How to get the generated SQL out of an IQueryable: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6df9599f-c165-4a0e-9b92-ca58a8fc3816/

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni much easier to just use MiniProfiler :p

Comment: Thanks for pointing out MiniProfiler, Marc.... I hadn't gone hunting for a NuGet package for sql profiling since my googling turned up a fairly direct method.

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is already in memory for other reasons, I suppose you could use this approach. Otherwise, a database would probably be better as you won't be loading 500k records into memory at one time.

```
select * from Books b where b.name IN {"foo", "bar", ...}
```

Comment: it isn't clear that the OP *is* returning 500,000 records - and in the question it is an equality match; using `LIKE` changes the meaning and *definitely* changes the performance.

Comment: ahh you're correct. I thought he wanted the name to contain the word foo or bar rather than the name being contained in the set of {"foo", "bar"}, ty